# click on one of the buttons in a jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, dialog

A question about jQuery UI dialogs. I'm creating an auto-login feature and I want to give some visual feedback. Login is done with jQuery UI dialogs.

Question: how do I force a click on the submit-button?

In the samples on the site the form hasn't got any properties set, so there must be another function triggered when the button is clicked manually.

I want to program a click on one of the buttons in a jQuery UI dialog.

Anyone that knows how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open the dialog you can find the buttons and add Ids on them to select using `#`.

This is an option on the `dialog()` function.

```
        open: function () {
            //assign ids/classes to buttons
            var buttonPane$ = $(this).siblings('.ui-dialog-buttonpane');

            var okButton = buttonPane$.find('button:contains("OK")');
            okButton.addClass('ui-priority-primary');
            okButton.attr('id', 'yourIdHere');
        }
```

When you need to trigger the click use `$('#yourIdHere').click();`

### Edit

If you create that as a function outside of the dialog, you can add it to the dialog options *and* call it directly instead of simulating a click on the button.

Comment: Or you can select form them in many other ways - `nth-child` for example, or `input:submit` etc.

Comment: I'm trying to open the dialog and submit it right away. So I was kind of gambling to have the click in the open: function()... I tried $(this).siblings(".ui-button").find('button:contains("login")').click(); from the open function, but that didn't do anything...

Comment: Do you have a click function handler that submits or use a form?

Comment: No, I use all functionality from the UI dialog.

Comment: ah, ok, sorry... I do have a handler. It's defined in one of the buttons. 

'$("dialog-form-login").dialog({'
'autoOpen: false,'
'modal: true,'
'buttons: {'
'forgot password': function( data ) { ... },'
'login': function( data ) { .. here is the login code.. },'

Comment: If you create that as a function outside of the dialog, you can add it to the dialog options <i>and</i> call it directly instead of simulating a click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I've miss understood your question,

to add a click function to things using Jquery you can use the code

```
('#idOfElement').click(function(){...});
```

However as was pointed out dialog buttons don't have id's

The way you do it is in the code that setups up your dialog...

```
$( "#someElement" ).dialog({
        buttons: {
            "text on the button": function() {
                //do something
            },
```

Comment: Dialog buttons don't have ids.

Comment: I know of this function, but in this case that doesn't work...  

every button in a dialog looks like this: 

<button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">login</span></button>

there is no id or class to identify the specific button...

Comment: The method shown be Decad does work. the function() is your .click.

Comment: How are you setting up your dialog? if your using jquery all your buttons will be setup within the dialog object, shown in the second code snippet